# $Y$ is a ( closed) proper subspace of a real NLS $X$ such that $dist (x,Y)=1$ for some $x \in X$ with $||x||=1$ ; is $Y$ finite dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $Y$ be a finite dimensional proper subspace of a real NLS $X$ , we know that we can find $x\in X$ ( depending on $Y$) , such that $||x||=1$ and $dist (x,Y):=\{||x-y||:y\in Y\}=1$ . I would like to ask the converse ; i.e.,

let $Y$ be a proper subspace ( also assume $Y$ is closed if  necessary)  of a real NLS $X$ such that $\exists x \in X$ such that $||x||=1$ and $dist (x,Y)=1$ , then is $Y$ finite dimensional ?

Answer (score 0):

No. What you want holds for every closed proper subspace of a Hilbert space.

Simply take any $x \in Y^\perp $ with $\|x\|=1$.